# webview and listview in a same activity

Tags: android, listview, webview

i'm trying to make a webview and listview in a same activity. i have a list view with id `list_xc` but in a logcat show in my `content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list`.
here's my layout file :

```
<com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar
    android:id="@+id/actionbar"
    style="@style/ActionBar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_xc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:text="Cross Country (XC)"
    android:textColor="#372c24"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview_xc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="166dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_xc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

and here's my row layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#424545" >
</TextView>
```

and here's my activity :

```
public class Information_XC_Activity extends ListActivity {
WebView mWebView;
TextView tv;
private Adapter_DetailPolXC adapterDetailPolXC;

private ListView mainListView;

// private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info_xc);

    final ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
    actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

    int index = getIntent().getIntExtra("text", 0);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_xc);

    String temp = "<html><body>" + "<p align=\"justify\">"
            + getString(R.string.xc_info + index) + "</p> "
            + "</body></html>";
    mWebView.loadData(temp, "text/html", "utf-8");

    ArrayList<Entity_Detail_Product> arraylist = new ArrayList<Entity_Detail_Product>();

    adapterDetailPolXC = new Adapter_DetailPolXC(this, R.layout.info_row,
            arraylist);

    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_xc);
    mainListView.setAdapter(adapterDetailPolXC);

    new info_xc_dao(response).view_pol_xc();
}

pol_xc_Result response = new pol_xc_Result() {
    @Override
    public void gotResult(Object obj, String message, int action) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // actionBar.setProgressBarVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<Entity_Detail_Product> arrayList = (ArrayList<Entity_Detail_Product>) obj;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Information_XC_Activity.this);

        if (arrayList == null) {
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_warning);
            builder.setTitle("Error");
            builder.setMessage("Data Not Found !");
            builder.setNegativeButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        } else {
            for (Entity_Detail_Product entity_Detail_Product : arrayList) {
                adapterDetailPolXC.add(entity_Detail_Product);
            }
            adapterDetailPolXC.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

};

private class Adapter_DetailPolXC extends
        ArrayAdapter<Entity_Detail_Product> {
    private ArrayList<Entity_Detail_Product> items;

    public Adapter_DetailPolXC(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Entity_Detail_Product> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = (View) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_xc, null);
        }
        Entity_Detail_Product adapter_Detail_Product = items.get(position);
        if (adapter_Detail_Product != null) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_test);
            if (textView != null)
                textView.setText(adapter_Detail_Product.getModel_name());
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

and here's the logcat :

> 09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wilis.hellotabwidget/com.wilis.hellotabwidget.Information_XC_Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:212)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at com.wilis.hellotabwidget.Information_XC_Activity.onCreate(Information_XC_Activity.java:35)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   09-21 03:22:49.029: E/AndroidRuntime(22732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)

thankyou so much, i really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListActivity does not require that you assign a layout to it via the setContentView() method, if you only want to show a ListView ListActivity contains by default a ListView.

In case you need to include more Views than a ListView in your ListActivity you can still assign a layout to your Activity. In this case your **layout must contain a ListView with the android:id attribute set to @android:id/list**. so modify code to this.

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

If you use a View with the @android:id/empty ID in your layout, ListActivity will automatically show this View if the ListView is empty and hide it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `Information_XC_Activity` extends `ListActivity`, it  must have a ListView with the id specified in the error message. Change this line

```
android:id="@+id/list_xc"
```

to this:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you extends ListActivity, your android:id="@+id/list_xc" must be android:id="@android:id/list"